# How to summarize character, factors, and numeric vectors in R

Tags: r, character, aggregate, summarize

I am trying to use summarize_all to find the average value of each ID. I can do this successfully for the ID column and the column I am trying to find the average for (speed). However, when I use the below code, all other column are returned as NAs.

The second problem is that some IDs have multiple locations sites or drivers. So I need to keep the speed averaged by driver but have multiples rows that maintain the unique driver and location (date doesn't matter)

I thought this might be because the columns that are returning as NAs are non-numeric. I tried looking through other questions, but couldn't fond one that answers why this happens and how to fix it.

I also tried using the aggregate() function but the same happens.

This is the code I am currently using:

```
library(dplyr)
avg <- bind %>%
group_by(ID) %>%
summarize_all(mean)
```

This is what my data looks like:

```
ID Speed Location Driver Date
2  100     a        1     M
2  145     a        1     M
5  155     b        1     M
4  100     a        2     T
3  135     b        2     T
3  156     b        3     T
4  167     b        3     W
```

This is what I would like the final dataset to look like:

```
ID Speed Location Driver Date
2  122.5   a        1     M
5  155     b        1     M
4  133     a        2     T
4  133     b        3     W
3  145.5   b        2     T
3  145.5   b        3     T
```

So far, this is what my result looks like:

```
ID Speed Location Driver Date
2  122.5   NA      NA     NA
5  155     NA      NA     NA
4  133     NA      NA     NA
4  133     NA      NA     NA
3  145.5   NA      NA     NA
3  145.5   NA      NA     NA
```

with the error code:

```
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

Comment: @akrun: I think they get the NA's when trying to use `summarise_all`. Your deleted answer looked right to me, I was just about to post the same thing.

Comment: Sorry, I input the wrong code example. I fixed this now. @akrun

Comment: Just want to point out that that's a warning, not an error. The code should still run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could replace the 'Speed' with `mean` of 'Speed' and then get the `distinct` rows

```
library(dplyr)
bind %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(Speed = mean(Speed)) %>%
    distinct()
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   ID [4]
#     ID Speed Location Driver Date 
#  <int> <dbl> <chr>     <int> <chr>
#1     2  122. a             1 M    
#2     5  155  b             1 M    
#3     4  134. a             2 T    
#4     3  146. b             2 T    
#5     3  146. b             3 T    
#6     4  134. b             3 W
```

---

The `NA`s in other columns would be the result of calling `mean` on non-numeric columns.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to summarize non-numeric columns? for example, one if my columns has the exact same value for each ID. Id like to have that attached to each average.

Comment: @Cae.rich  How do you want to summarise non-numeric columns.  `mean` works only on numeric columns.  e.g when you have values like, 'M', "W', do you want to get `M.W`

Comment: @Cae.rich  If you meant to get the `distinct`, `bind %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Speed = mean(Speed)) %>% distinct()
`